# Number error in parsing json

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax

I have a php class( ajax called) which returns `json_encode` data as

```
["2016-02-08 09:00:00.000","2016-02-15 09:00:00.000"]
```

I'm trying to do `jquery.parseJSON(data)` and it's giving me error `"Unexpected number"`, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do a `console.log(data);` right before and maybe it's not what you're expecting.

Comment: *"ajax called"* - Why are you calling parseJSON() yourself? If you set the dataType property correctly in the Ajax call jquery will automatically parse it for you and pass the resulting object to your success handler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to parse an array, not a string. `JSON.parse` (and any other JSON parser) expects a string, therefore `Array.toString` is called and your call becomes `jquery.parseJSON("2016-02-08 09:00:00.000,2016-02-15 09:00:00.000")`

```
//Error "Unexpected number", toString is called on the input array
JSON.parse(["2016-02-08 09:00:00.000","2016-02-15 09:00:00.000"]) 
// Returns an array object
JSON.parse('["2016-02-08 09:00:00.000","2016-02-15 09:00:00.000"]') // OK
```

If you are using the return of `json_encode` inline, you don't need to parse it, just assign it to a variable, JavaScript will do the parsing.

```
var dates = <?= json_encode($dates) ?>;
```

If you are using `jQuery` the data will typically already be parsed into JSON in the callback, if it doesn't, you can force it using  `dataType: 'json'`

Answer (score 0):

```
var x = '["2016-02-08 09:00:00.000","2016-02-15 09:00:00.000"]';
$.parseJSON(x) // return an array
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery does the decoding for you when you perform the AJAX call with the JSON dataType:

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'mypage.php',
  data: mydata,
  dataType: 'json'
})
.done(function(response) {
   // Response is an array, not a JSON string, jQuery decoded it.
   // Demo:
   console.log(response[0]); // "2016-02-08 09:00:00.000"
   console.log(response[1]); // "2016-02-15 09:00:00.000"
}
```

This is explained in the [jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/):

> **dataType**
>
> ...
> `"json"`: Evaluates the response as JSON and returns a JavaScript object.

So, don't use `jquery.parseJSON` on the result. It has already been done for you.